# Function to aggregate json

Tags: python, pandas

Assume I have a gcs bucket with json files with the following structure:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Name": "alibaba",
    "storeid": "Y1",
    "storeName": "alibaba1",
    "a": "1/2/3",
    "b": "1.0/1.0/3",
    "c": "0/0/0",
    "d": "0/0/0",
    "e": "1.8/3.4",
    "f": "1/2/3",
    "g": "1/2/3",
  },
  {
    "Id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Name": "alibaba",
    "storeUuid": "Y2",
     "storeName": "alibaba2",
    "a": "1/2/3",
    "b": "1.0/1.0/3",
    "c": "0/0/0",
    "d": "0/0/0",
    "e": "1.7/2.4",
    "f": "1/2/3",
    "g": "1/2/3",
  },
  {
    "Id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Name": "alibaba",
    "storeUuid": "Y3",
     "storeName": "alibaba3",
    "a": "1/2/3",
    "b": "1.0/1.0/3",
    "c": "0/0/0",
    "d": "0/0/0",
    "e": "2.7/4.4",
    "f": "1/2/3",
    "g": "1/2/3",
  },
  {
    "Id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Name": "alibaba",
    "storeUuid": "Y4",
     "storeName": "alibaba4",
    "a": "1/2/3",
    "b": "1.0/1.0/3",
    "c": "0/0/0",
    "d": "0/0/0",
    "e": "3.7/5.4",
    "f": "1/2/3",
    "g": "1/2/3",
  }
]
```

What I want to do is to aggregate the different values by summing `a, b,c, d, f,g` and taking the average of `e` to return one single `json` like

```
[
{
    "Id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Name": "alibaba",
    "a": "sum over all first instance/sum over all second instances/sum aover all third instance",
    "b": "sum over all first instance/sum over all second instances/sum aover all third instance",
    "c": "sum over all first instance/sum over all second instances/sum aover all third instance",
    "d": "sum over all first instance/sum over all second instances/sum aover all third instance",
    "e": "average over all first instance/average over all second instance",
    "f": "sum over all first instance/sum over all second instances/sum aover all third instance",
    "g": "sum over all first instance/sum over all second instances/sum aover all third instance",
  }
]
```

Not that any of the values in `*/*/*` could be NaN and that the data in `e` could be a string `data unvavailable`.

In have created this function

```
def format_large_numbers_optimized(value):
    abs_values = np.abs(value)
    mask = abs_values >= 1e6
    formatted_values = np.where(mask, 
                                np.char.add(np.round(value / 1e6, 2).astype(str), "M"), 
                                np.round(value, 2).astype(str))
    return formatted_values

def process_json_data_optimized(json_list):
    result = {}
    keys = set(json_list[0].keys()) - {'Id', 'Name', 'storeid', 'storeName'}
    for key in keys:
        result[key] = {'values': []}
    for json_data in json_list:
        for key in keys:
            value = json_data.get(key, '0')  
            result[key]['values'].append(value)
    for key in keys:
        all_values_processed = []
        for value in result[key]['values']:
            if isinstance(value, str) and '/' in value:
                processed_values = [float(v) if v != 'data unavailable' else 0 for v in value.split('/')]
            elif isinstance(value, float) or isinstance(value, int):
                processed_values = [value]
            else:
                processed_values = [0.0]  
            all_values_processed.append(processed_values)
        numeric_values = np.array(all_values_processed)
        if numeric_values.ndim == 1:
            numeric_values = numeric_values[:, np.newaxis]
        summed_values = np.sum(numeric_values, axis=0)
        formatted_summed_values = '/'.join(format_large_numbers_optimized(summed_values))
        result[key]['summed'] = formatted_summed_values
    processed_result = {key: data['summed'] for key, data in result.items()}
    processed_result['Id'] = json_list[0]['Id']
    processed_result['Name'] = json_list[0]['Name']
    return processed_result
```

But it does not create what I expect. I am a at a total loss. Would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are placing the values as lists `all_values_processed`.
Assuming that the `/` character is just a separator, and that what you want by replacing `all_values_processed.append(processed_values)` by `all_values_processed += processed_values`. Or even better you could just aggregate the values.

For instance you could have a function to aggregate like this

```py
import math
def agg_func(value, initial):
  v_count, v_sum = initial
  if isinstance(value, str) and '/' in value:
    for v in value.split('/'):
      if v != 'data unavailable' :
         v = float(v)
         if not math.isnan(v):
           v_sum += v
           v_count += 1
  elif isinstance(value, float) or isinstance(value, int):
    if not math.isnan(value):
      v_sum += value
      v_count += 1
  return v_count, v_sum
```

A function that aggregate the given keys in the json

```py
def agg_json(v_list, fields):
  state = {k: (0, 0) for k in fields}
  for item in v_list:
    for k in fields:
      if k in item:
        state[k] = agg(item[k], state[k])
  return state
```

Now

```py
state = agg_json(json_list, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
```

will give you a dictionary with tuples containing the count and the sum for each field. To get your final answer you could do

```py
result = {k: v[1] / v[0] if k == 'e' else v[1] for k, v in state.items()}
```

Comment: Great answer! It work as it should. I need to adapt the method to the rest of my code as it is a part of a cloud function. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) and if I got the OP right, here is a potential generic solution :

```
IN_SEP = OUT_SEP = "/"

ids = ["Id", "Name"]
metrics = df.columns.difference(
    [*ids, "storeUuid", "storeName"], sort=False
)
aggs = dict.fromkeys(metrics.difference(["e"]), "sum") | {"e": "mean"}

out = (
    df.set_index(ids, append=True)[metrics]
    .stack().str.split(IN_SEP, expand=True)
    .apply(pd.to_numeric,errors="coerce")
    .unstack().stack(0, future_stack=True)
    .groupby(level=list(range(1, len(ids) + 2)))
    .agg(aggs).round(2).groupby(ids).agg(
        lambda s: s.astype(str).replace("nan", "")
         .str.cat(sep=OUT_SEP).strip(OUT_SEP))[metrics]
    .reset_index().to_dict("records")
)
```

Output :

```
print(json.dumps(out, indent=4))

[
    {
        "Id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "Name": "alibaba",
        "a": "4.0/8.0/12.0",
        "b": "4.0/4.0/12.0",
        "c": "0.0/0.0/0.0",
        "d": "0.0/0.0/0.0",
        "e": "2.48/3.9",
        "f": "4.0/8.0/12.0",
        "g": "4.0/8.0/12.0"
    }
]
```

Used input :

```
# with a fixed typo in the 1st record : "storeUuid" instead of "storeid"
with open("file.json", "r") as file:
    import json # if json-fmt
    # json_list = json.load(file)

    from ast import literal_eval
    json_list = literal_eval(file.read())

    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame(json_list)
```